# Configure MS DTC over VPN

Tags: vpn, msdtc

I tried to configure MS DTC via our VPN. But when I try to open the connection it gives me the following error.

> The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to push the transaction to the destination transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02A)

When I check with the network team they told me that the firewall is already configured to allow DTC.

If I explain this further this communication is done via VPN. According to my network admin, although the client machine could see the NetBios name of the server but server cannot see the client's NetBios name, when this communication is done through a firewall/router. He is telling that, to start a DTC communication both machines should be able to see their NetBios names.

I tried with DTCPing (Same setup) and the dtc ping error is

```
03-04, 10:18:33.918-->RPC server:NGSVR received following information:
    Network Name: NGSVR
    Source  Port: 49179
    Partner LOG: WS-PCSPOS76036.log
    Partner CID: EBA77A41-C9F9-4162-B7A2-E10404719072
++++++++++++Start Reverse Bind Test+++++++++++++
Received Bind call from WS-PCSPOS7
    Network Name: NGSVR
    Source  Port: 49179
    Hosting Machine:NGSVR
03-04, 10:18:33.996-->Trying to Reverse Bind to WS-PCSPOS7...
    Test Guid:EBA77A41-C9F9-4162-B7A2-E10404719072
gethostbyname can not resolve WS-PCSPOS7
Error(0xB7) at nameping.cpp @43
-->gethostbyname failure
-->183(Cannot create a file when that file already exists.)
Can not resolve WS-PCSPOS7
Error(0x6BA) at ServerManager.cpp @453
-->RPC reverse BIND failed
-->1722(The RPC server is unavailable.)
Reverse Binding to WS-PCSPOS7 Failed
    In  GUID
    Out GUID
Reverse BIND FAILED
Session Down
```

I have tried to open and do a transaction via non vpn setup and it was successful.

Can we configure MS DTC via VPN?
If it is possible any additional configuration should do to VPN?